# How to run code on App Start-up in React-Native

Tags: react-native

So I have a react-native application and want to run some code on app start-up;

The application has background task handlers(android) which (to the best of my knowledge) does not mount any views so initializing stuff in the root constructor or componentDidMount may not work.

I want to add certain database listeners to my application which get triggered even while the app is being run in background.

Any help on the same would be highly appreciated.
Thanks regards.
Amol.

Comment: Could you give an example of one of these scenarios please?

Comment: So i am fetching some data from the server(via a pull request sent from fcm) and adding it to the local database. On adding to a specific table i want to trigger some event. For which i need to add a listener to the database table(i am using Realm in this case.).

Comment: In expo you can use AppLoading and in normal react native you can use react-native-splashscreen to do something when the app starts

Comment: @yesIamFaded screen are not loaded when app is in background, secondly the listeners need to be un-registered after the the screen is unmounted, i have my doubt if this helps but thanks anyway

Answer (score 8):

In functional components, you want to use the [`useEffect()` method with an empty dependency array](https://www.reactnative.express/react/hooks/useeffect#undefined-or-empty-dependency-array):

```js
useEffect(() => {
  // this code will run once
}, [])
```

When an empty dependency array (`[]`) is used, the `useEffect()` callback is called only once, right after the component renders for the first time.

Use like this:

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'

export default function App () {
  useEffect(() => {
    // this code will run once
  }, [])

  // ...
}
```